# Why "cd .." doesn't work in this if

Tags: bash

```
pwd | grep 'database$'
if [ "$?" = 0 ]; then
echo "has db"
cd ..
cd ..
echo "after has db"
fi
```

after I execute it I see

```
has db
after has db
```

and I'm still in the same dir, how to fix it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think it has to do with how you run the script.

If you do:

```
sh ./script.sh
```

Or

```
./script.sh
```

Then it invokes a new shell, runs the script, then returns you to the current one. So the cd is done in the new shell and your current one is untouched.

Try this instead:

```
. ./script.sh
```

Which will run script.sh in your current shell, and you'll keep the results after it finishes.

Comment: @UAdapter: to be sure that the issue is how u r running the script and not with the script, try printing the current working directory from the script before and after executing each cd command.

Answer (score 1):

A function would be more suitable for a command like this. E.g.

```
back() {
    if [[ $PWD = *database ]]; then
        cd ../../
    fi
}
```

Put it in ~/.bashrc to have this new `back` command available in new interactive bash sessions.